# Is it appropriate to say "Grüß Gott" (God greets you) to Muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, non-muslim-countries, greetings

In Upper Germany, people greet each other by saying "Grüß Gott". It has the same function as English "good morning".

This greeting means "God greets you", however, nowadays it has mostly non-religious meaning. People say "Grüß Gott" no matter if they are members of any religion or not. I am an atheist and I use that greeting too, as everyone else.

I am not sure if I should use "Grüß Gott" toward Muslim people. Regions where "Grüß Gott" is used are fulfilled with vast majority of Catholic religion. Maybe for a Muslim person "Grüß Gott" may sound as "my God greets you", which may be not nice for him/her? The Bible says, that "the God is only one". Thus, can be "Grüß Gott" even offensive?

Where I live, people all around say "Grüß Gott" toward Muslims, since it's the culture of that region. However, if this greeting is not something nice for Muslim people, I would want to respect them and use some other greeting.

Maybe is there any person living in that area who can tell his/her thoughts about that topic?

Answer (score 2):

In Arabic, we often say this to greet other people when we meet them:

حياك الله --- الله يحييك

The literal translation of these two phrases is:
"may Allah greet you", "Greetings of Allah upon you"

So there is no problem to use the phrase if it has that meaning.

Comment: It's a short nice answer, Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score -1):

There is no disrespect if God greets someone. as greeting is a good habit and greeting makes people happy. Our God is all loving and merciful and I am sure if God has a chance to greet anyone, he sure will, because God has good manners and thats the fundamental difference between God and Devil.

A devil may not necessarily greet you. he may punch you in the nose because the devil is condemned and lacks decency and good manners.

So, if someone says God greets you, you should say thank you. You may also say God has greeted me and blessed me beyond what I deserve.

Answer (score -2):

Saying my god greets you isn't offensive in Islam, and I had an Austrian friend say this to me every time, didn't really mind it myself and generally it does not offend Islam nor Muslims :) .

stranger